# Refer to Wildcard in File Name

Tags: bash, wildcards

I know I can use a wildcard to extract files with names of a specific format in bash using the asterisk, like so:

```
$ ls
a01     a02     a03     a04     a05     a06     a07     a08     a09     b01     b02     b03     b04     b05     b06     b07     b08     b09
$ ls a*
a01     a02     a03     a04     a05     a06     a07     a08     a09
$ ls b*
b01     b02     b03     b04     b05     b06     b07     b08     b09
```

But if I wanted to do something like move all the files starting with a to a directory called  `a` and move all the files starting with b to a directory called `b`, how would I do that with one command?

Can you do something like this:

```
$ mv *0* */
```

But somehow reference the first asterisk in the move-to argument?

Answer (score 0):

One command, one line:

```
for n in *;do [ -f "$n" ] && case "$n" in a*) mv "$n" a/;; b*) mv "$n" b/;; esac; done
```

Alternatively, you could derive the name of the directory from the filename, but I did not show that initially, estimating it to be a longer line.  For example, the statement in the loop would be (first try):

```
d=$(echo "$n" | sed -e 's/^\(.\).*/\1/'); [ -f "$n" ] && mv "$n" $d/
```

would use the first letter of the given filename to obtain the directory name.  Compare with

```
[ -f "$n" ] && case "$n" in a*) mv "$n" a/;; *b) mv "$n" b/;; esac
```

for the case-statement.  Actually not much longer, but harder to type on the fly.  Because `bash` is mentioned, one can use its substring syntax `${parameter:offset:length}` to shorten that line:

```
d=${n:0:1}; [ -f "$n" ] && mv "$n" $d/
```

or

```
[ -f "$n" ] && mv "$n" ${n:0:1}/
```

(I recall this as a bash extension, and do not find it in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18)).

Regarding the actual question about reusing wildcards: that apparently refers to [*brace expansion*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).  Those are expanded before the point where you would need them.  Quoting the documentation:

> Brace expansion is performed **before** any other expansions, and any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. It is **strictly textual**. Bash does **not** apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces. To avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ‘${’ is not considered eligible for brace expansion.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot more convoluted than I expected. So there isn't something like backreferences in regex?

Comment: yes/no: not with wildcards, but only for the expanded names.  The loop I showed hard-codes the names and looks long -- but translating the name would add about a third to the length of the line, so I stopped there.  The example makes sure that the source is a file, which makes it a *little* longer.

Comment: bash does have substitutions which would avoid `sed` -- I do most of my scripting for POSIX applications.